# PrimeFaces programmatic dialog box alignment

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am calling below code from managed bean as

```java
PrimeFaces.current().dialog().showMessageDynamic(
  new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error",
                   "Test creation Failed. Please try again!")
);
```

If I call above code with different message having size greater than above message then alignment of dialogue is not proper. e.g.

```java
PrimeFaces.current().dialog().showMessageDynamic(
  new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error",
                   "Please provide Valid Test Name.Test Name can not be blank and cannot contains any special character other than Underscore and Hyphen")
);
```

Is there any way to make sure dialogue should appear at correct alignment(centre) irrespective of message length? Is there any way to pass CSS while calling from managed bean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following:

```java
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('yourDialog').initPosition()");
```

Comment: Ha, we created a custom renderer for the dialog to do that `onShow` by default.

Comment: but are using PrimeFaces.current().dialog().showMessageDynamic("") , so above approach wont work. we dont have predefined dialog in xhtml.